Merging points by distance
I have a point data layer for bus stops, some of the points are located close together. For example when the same bus serves both directions, resulting in stops on opposite sides of the street. I would like to merge these two points into one, positioned in the middle of the two original points.
In my dataset the points have an indication field that I can use. However, there are certain bus stops serving opposite directions that are too far apart from each other so they should not be merged.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?
I am using QGIS for my project.

what software are you using? what have you tried so far?

Do you have a field indicating that your point are the "same" stop in opposite direction or do you need to use only distance between stop ? are there some case when close point shouldn't be merged ?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification.

If only for visualisation you may use the QGIS symbology renderer "Point Cluster", it will let you choose at witch distance the point should be merged

Its not just for visualising
